# attachment is not proper in mail in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, attachment

i'm sending a mail with attachment(1.pdf) but in mail it doesnt shows 1.pdf instead it shows some random file named "ATT008220.dat".

i'm using Rails 3.0
following is the code i'm using:

```
        @file = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
        @file.force_encoding('BINARY')
        attachment "application/octet-stream" do |a|
            a.body = @file
        end
```

anybody knows why its happening? any idea?

Thanks & Regards,

Harsh Raval.

EDIT::----
The mail sending method:

```
def contact(recipient, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)   
    @subject = subject
    @recipients = recipient
    @from = 'harsh@apprika.com'
    @sent_on = sent_at
    @body = message
    #@file = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
    #@file.force_encoding('US_ASCII')
    #attachment "multipart/alternative" do |a|
    #   a.body = @file
    #end
    attachments['1.pdf'] =  {:mime_type => 'application/pdf',:content => File.read('c:/1.pdf')}
    @headers = {}
end
```

Comment: Did you try specifying "application/pdf" instead of "application/octet-stream"?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem trying to send a mail with an .xlsx file as attachment. To make it work I had to do:

```
attachments['filename.xlsx'] = {
  :encoding => 'base64',
  :content  => Base64.encode64(File.read(filename))
}
```

This is mentioned partially in section 2.3.2 of the Mailer guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods

Comment: THANK YOU. This looks like an incredible bug. The docs say that the library will base64-encode the content.

Comment: FYI the method name seems to have changed from `Base64.b64encode` to `Base64.encode64`

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to specify file name

```
@file = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
@file.force_encoding('BINARY')
attachment "application/octet-stream" do |a|
  a.body = @file
  a.filename = "1.pdf"
end
```

And I would use `"application/pdf"` for pdf file.

EDIT:

I looked to Rails 3 guides and I don't see any example with above syntax. Instead they use something like this:

```
attachments['1.pdf'] = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
```

Or with additional options:

```
attachments['1.pdf'] = {:mime_type => 'application/octet-stream',                              
                           :content => File.read('c:/1.pdf') }
```

Take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods) for more informations.

EDIT 2:

I want to answer your questions from comments. I haven't used mailer in Rails 3, but I use it in Rails 2.3.X and here is some code that works for me:

```
attachment :content_type => "application/msword",
  :body => File.read("files/word.doc"),
  :filename => "word.doc"

attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
  a.body = File.read("files/some_pdf.pdf")
  a.filename = "umowa.pdf"
end
```

In Rails 3 mailer API has changed. And you should use new API. Btw. you can also try if my first example works - it uses hash instead of block.

ANOTHER EDIT:

I think you should use `mail` object to send mail. Here is example from Rails Guides:

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  @url  = user_url(@user)
  mail(:to => user.email,
     :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
end
```

And `message` should be rendered in mailer view. I think you have problems with it, because you are mixing old mailer API with new one. Take a look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) to see how to do it in "new way" step by step.

Comment: it gives error:    undefined method `filename=' for #<Mail::Part:0x24b94a8>

Comment: Have you try it cause i've already tried it. it send content data in body that is something we cant read. It does not attach anything.

Comment: @Harsh: I answered your question in my answer. If it works as you said, then please attach whole method from mailer, not only attachment part.

Comment: @klew: you can see my method in my question.

Comment: @klew: yes i've seen your answer and workin on it.and will reply you soon as i get output.

Comment: @klew: thanks. working on an old Rails 2 app and :filename is just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

As of Rails 3(x) your **content disposition** is what determines the way the file name is received by the end user.

Instead of:

```
attachments['1.pdf'] =  {:mime_type => 'application/pdf',:content => File.read('c:/1.pdf')}
```

Use this:

```
# I like to rewrite the file name to exclude any whitespaces
safe_name = file_name.gsub(/[^0-9a-z\.]/i,"-")
attachments[safe_name] = {
  :content  => File.read(file_name),
  :content_disposition => "attachment; filename=\"#{safe_name}\""
}
```

You can include the mime_type but unless you explain the order in which the attachments should be included you could end up with some unsavory results unless you specify in your mailer something like so:

```
class SampleNotifications < ActionMailer::Base

  # my_mailer
  :content_type => 'multipart/alternative',
  :parts_order => [ "text/plain", "text/enriched", "text/html", "application/octet-stream" ]

  def notify
    ... something like the code above
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

add following to actionmailer:-

```
def send_mail
    attachments['1.pdf'] = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
    mail(:to => "harsh@xyz.com", :subject => "xyz", :from=>"harsh@xyz.com")
    mail.deliver
end
```

Notes:- Make sure that the smtp settings are correct and the file corresponding to the action (In this example send_mail.rhtml) is present under appropriate folder.

Hope this helps.