# email not proper in rails 3

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3

I've same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560896/attachment-is-not-proper-in-mail-in-rails). But still not able to solve it.

I've followed steps from [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3). but doing so doesn't sends mail.

The log file says: Mail is sent. but at the other side mail is not received.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem is solved. Problem was my file corresponding to action was not at proper place. Here is quick view on how to do it:

Add following to actionmailer:-

```
def send_mail
    attachments['1.pdf'] = File.read('c:/1.pdf')
    mail(:to => "harsh@xyz.com", :subject => "xyz", :from=>"harsh@xyz.com")
    mail.deliver
end
```

Notes:- Make sure that the smtp settings are correct and the file corresponding to the action (In this example send_mail.rhtml) is present under appropriate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SMTP settings and make sure you have defined the right settings for your e-mail host. If you are using a sender e-mail other than Gmail then your settings will be different to the ones used in the Railscast.

The file to check is here: `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`.

**Edit:** It still may be possible that the settings you used in jsp may not match perfectly with the 'phrasing' that Rails expects in the `setup_mail.rb` file. I have frequently come up against this problem where a slight difference in what SMTP settings you mention / don't mention / how they are worded will determine whether the e-mails send/receive or not.

If your logs show the e-mail is sending to a valid e-mail address (and you are not receiving those e-mails in your inbox or spam filter) then the problem, as far as I know, is most likely to be your SMTP. My advice is to check online for the Rails-specific SMTP settings for your e-mail provider, or in the case that you cannot find them, try different combinations until you find the correct one.

Comment: The mail settings are correct. I've used the same setting in other project using JSP.

Comment: do you have any other idea on why this is not sending mail.

Comment: @Harry, I've added some more information above. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: if i shift the code from setup_mail.rb to environment.rb then its working fine. Now the mail is received at the other side but without body and attachment.Only subject and from field is filled with data. ???

Comment: Okay the problem is solved. Problem was my file corresponding to action was not at proper place.